# SharePoint 2013 list search box and Client Site Rendering (JSLink)

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, jslink, client-side-rendering

Im trying to implement a FAQ accordion SharePoint list.
I managed to get the accordion working while using JSLink.
Sadly the search is not working properly.
I used the following code in my JSLink js:

```
(function () {
/*
 * Initialize the variable that store the overrides objects.
 */
var overrideCtx = {};
overrideCtx.Templates = {
    Header: function(ctx) {
            var headerHtml =  RenderTableHeader(ctx);
            headerHtml += "</table>";
            headerHtml += "<div id='accordion'>";
            return headerHtml;
        },
    Footer: function (ctx) {
        return "</div>";
                        },
    Item: function(ctx) {
        // Build a listitem entry for every announcement in the list.
        var ret = "<h3 class='OutlookFAQ'>"+ctx.CurrentItem.Title+"</h3><div style='display:none;' class='OutlookFAQContent'><p>"+ctx.CurrentItem.Answer+"</p></div>";
        return ret;
    }

};


overrideCtx.BaseViewID = 1;
overrideCtx.ListTemplateType = 100;



overrideCtx.OnPostRender = [];
overrideCtx.OnPostRender.push(function()
{
    $('#accordion h3').click(function(e) {
            $(e.target).next('div').siblings('div').slideUp();
            $(e.target).next('div').slideToggle();
    });
});

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);

})();
```

As i sad, the accordion is working, the searchbox is beeing display. If I try to submit search a JS Error "TypeError: this.$T_3 is null" in sp.ui.listsearchbox.js pops up.
Any ideas?

Regards

René

Comment: I suppose you follow this blog post: http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/01/using-jslink-to-change-ui-of-sharepoint_20.html ?

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs due to the missing `Search Status` element which is a part of search control and rendered in `Footer` template

### Search Status

Search status element is used to display hints about search results.
`RenderSearchStatus` function is used for rendering Search status

[image]

### Solution

Replace Footer rendering template

```
Footer: function (ctx) {
    return "</div>";   
}
```

with

```
Footer: function (ctx) {
   var footerHtml = "</div>";
   footerHtml += RenderFooterTemplate(ctx);  //render standard footer (pager, search status)
   return footerHtml;   
}
```

---

Blog post [Customize the rendering of a List View in Sharepoint 2013: Displaying List Items in Accordion](http://blog.vgrem.com/2013/04/14/customize-the-rendering-of-a-list-view-in-sharepoint-2013-displaying-list-items-in-accordion/) contains a working example of List View rendered as Accordion.

Comment: Great, thanks for your help. The search is now working, at least partly. When the search is executed, the rendering is totally wrong, when you clear the search, the rendering is even worse. I think my JS code is somehow wrong. Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: Hmm.. the answer has been updated, the mentioned post describes how to customize List View to render it as accordion